# Linear Search works with written word by user?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, linear-search

So i recently started learning C# and I have an assignment from my teacher. 
I have been stuck on the last part of the code and would like to know from people with more knowledge what I am doing wrong or if there is something I have forgotten.

The assignment is to let the user write maximum 5 words. Then the user can view the word he/she wrote. This part I have done and it works.

However the search part is confusing me. Im using array and  for-loop and the search part is still not working. Also worth mention is that I have assigned the array to Console.Readline();, meaning test[0] Console.Readline() and so on;, if it is of any help. 
So in short, I want to have a linear search that can find the written word. Also whatever I type when doing the search it says that the word exists.

This is the part I am stuck.

Comment: Please, [edit] your question and show us your whole code. Or, at leats, a more relevant block, the piece of code in the post doesn't even makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, that is what i thought, I added the whole code to see what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the words stored away in an Array, just use `Array.Contains` like this

```
string[] userWords = { "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4" };
string search = Console.ReadLine();
if(userWords.Contains(search))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Word " + search + " exists");
}
```

You have to include the `System.Linq` namespace for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you want to find a string from an array of strings. You can do this using a for loop.

```
string search=Console.ReadLine();
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    if(test[i]==search){
       Console.WriteLine("word: " + search + " exists.");
   }
}
```

Comment: So I have to write another for-loop? Because I already have one. Maybe I should be a little more clearer. I am using switch-method and the code i wrote is on case 4.